# MousePressEvent Not Functioning Correctly on Touchscreen

Tags: qt, user-interface, pyqt

I am noticing that my MousePressEvent functions are not working as intended when I use the touchscreen functionality of my computer.

The buttons on my GUI are intended to change color on a press event and on release, return to original color and perform a function.

There are four scenarios:

1. Mouse press on the QLabel button and instantly release - Works as intended
2. Mouse press on the QLabel button, drag mouse, and release (slight delay in hold) - Works as intended
3. Finger press on the QLabel and instantly release (normal tap) - does not change image color but performs the function in MouseReleaseEvent.
4. Finger press on the QLabel, drag finger, and release (slight delay in hold) - Works as intended

Even a long hold in the same position on scenario 3 doesn't cause the image to change color, I have to drag my finger for a 1/4 second to make it work.

This is my code:

```
self.saveImageBTN = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.cameraViewer)
self.saveImageBTN.setPixmap(QPixmap("Graphics/saveImageButton.png").scaled(100,100))
self.saveImageBTN.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 610, 100, 100))
self.saveImageBTN.setObjectName("saveImageBTN")
self.saveImageBTN.mousePressEvent = self.saveImageButtonPress
self.saveImageBTN.mouseReleaseEvent = self.saveImageButtonRelease

def saveImageButtonPress(self, event):
       self.saveImageBTN.setPixmap(QPixmap("Graphics/saveImageButtonPressed.png").scaled(100,100))

def saveImageButtonRelease(self, event):
       self.saveImageBTN.setPixmap(QPixmap("Graphics/saveImageButton.png").scaled(100,100))
       self.ImagePlayer.saveImage()
```

I have tried to add delays around the code in my saveImageButtonPress function to account for touchscreen latency but it doesn't seem to help.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: First of all, be aware that overwriting event handlers like that is discouraged as it might create some issues and make debugging difficult. Then, you should ensure that `saveImageButtonPress` gets called, the fact that you don't see the image change is probably because the event is fired so fast that the event loop hasn't had the time to change the image that you're already restoring it, so at least add a `print()` there. Then, if your attempt in adding delays was using blocking functions (like `time.sleep()`) it won't work, you should use a QTimer (or QElapsedTimer) and detect those events.

Comment: @musicamante So I did add some print statements and you are correct - both events are basically firing at the same time so the color change is not occurring since it gets overwritten.  I'm not sure by what you mean to use QTimer to detect the events - I need to basically build a delay into the MouseReleaseEvent

Comment: @musicamante I added a standard timer between the events and I am getting 0 microseconds time difference between the two functions when I use my fingers to press which I don't even know how that make sense. When I use the mouse I get anywhere from 0.1-0.3 seconds